# How to authenticate user in Spark

Tags: civicrm-spark

I'm using the [spark version of civicrm](https://civicrm.org/spark) and can set up CiviCRM contacts to be administrators, but am having trouble with user authentication (allowing users to log in).

The spark version runs under Drupal and I've read through the [Drupal directions](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/initial-set-up/permissions-and-access-control/#permissions-in-drupal), and maybe it's me, but the drupal interface doesn't seem to be particularly transparent.

Does anyone know how to allow authentication, or even if this is possible?

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by "authentication"? Do you mean logging in?

Comment: Sorry - missed your comment. That's right - I can't see a mechanism for a user, other than the initial admin user to log in

Comment: I consulted with the member of the CiviCRM core team who runs Spark, and he verified that you can create additional Drupal users (authenticated users). However at the moment there's only one access level: the same as yours.

Comment: Also, there's a distinction between CiviCRM contacts and Drupal users; I want to make sure we're not talking about CiviCRM contacts, who could be added to a group called "administrators" but this wouldn't (on its own) allow them to login.

Comment: That's right.  So the question now is how to add additional drupal users that can authenticate

Comment: Are you able to use https://yourdomain.org/admin/people/create ?

Comment: Yes that does the trick - thanks

Answer (score 4):

Here is how to add new user accounts* in the Spark interface (if you don't want to use the URL that [Noah](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/users/446/noah-miller) provides above).

**Step 1: Click the down arrow icon at the upper right of your screen.**

[image: screenshot of the down arrow icon with a pointer to it]

This will expose another menu.

**Step 2: Click "Manage Users" on that menu.**

[image: screenshot of the menu, with a pointer to "Manage Users"]

This will take you to the the screen where you can add new users.

*It might be helpful to review the [difference between CiviCRM contacts and user accounts](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/initial-set-up/users-contacts/).